# Update a value on a column only if that value is different from empty

Tags: php, mysql

I have this form, now, i need to update only the parts of the database with variables that are not empty.
I mean, if i have this:

```
$postEmri       = filter_var($_POST["postEmri"], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
$postKlienti        = filter_var($_POST["postKlienti"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$postTelefoni   = filter_var($_POST["postTelefoni"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
```

And this:

```
$sql="UPDATE forma SET emri='$postEmri', klienti='$postKlienti', telefoni='$postTelefoni'";
```

If `$postEmri, $postKlienti` are `undefined` or `empty`, i don't want that record to be updated.
How can i do it using some conditions?

Thanks

So i need to do this?

```
$sql="UPDATE forma SET ";
// add every non-empty field to the query
if (!empty($postEmri)) $sql += " emri='$postEmri',";
if (!empty($postKlienti)) $sql += " klienti='$postKlienti',";
if (!empty($postTelefoni)) $sql += " telefoni='$postTelefoni,'";
// replace the last `,` for `;`
$sql = substr($sql, 0, -1) . ";";
$result=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error()) ;
```

Comment: Try researching first please: use [`isset`](http://php.net/isset) and [`empty`](http://php.net/empty).

Comment: answer update, check it out

Comment: Well i pretty much gave you the same answer, except i checked if there actually were changed fields. Code above will throw a mysql error if no fields were changed.

Comment: And above could could result in an sql string `$sql = "UPDATE forma SET emri='value', SET klienti='value', set telefoni='value` which i believe to be invalid because of the extra SET's

Comment: There were a couple of extra "SET", I've update the question and answer. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to update only fields which are not empty:

```
$sqlStart="UPDATE forma SET ";
$sql="";
// add every non-empty field to the query
if (!empty($postEmri)) $sql .= " emri='$postEmri',";
if (!empty($postKlienti)) $sql .= " klienti='$postKlienti',";
if (!empty($postTelefoni)) $sql .= " telefoni='$postTelefoni,'";
// if any of the fields is non-empty, run the query
if ($sql != "") {
    // replace the last `,` for `;`
    $sql = substr($sql, 0, -1) . ";";
    // run sql command
    $sqlCommand = $sqlStart.$sql;
} else {
    // no fields to update
}
```

Comment: Please see my updated question once more, just to confirm it..!
because it will never happen for all the variables to ne undefined

Comment: Thanks, but i might be missing something, because it says query is empty..
maybe i need to add smth..

Comment: are you sure all the fields are non-empty? try printing out `$sql` just to make sure it has values and that the syntax is correct

Comment: i copy pasted it exactly like above;
and when i print the $sql i get this: (;) just that.. is strange though

Comment: mmm.. must be something you are missing, the above code should work.. any change your doing `$sql = ` instead of `$sql += `somewhere in the code?

Comment: Hmm i don't know, i'll check it though!
Anyways, i'm setting the answer as correct, the logic is correct though :)
thanks!

Comment: cool +1 :) if you want paste your complete code at [pastebin](http://pastebin.com) and i'll have a look

Comment: Oh ya dis is a better 1 +1 ;)

Answer (score 1):

you can use [empty](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php)

```
if (!empty($someVariable))
     //do something
```

Comment: !empty() also checks isset. empty($var) will return false if $var is not set.

Answer (score 0):

## Updated

You said you wanted to don't have "100 if-statements" if you had 100 post variables. Here's how you can do it then, this checks all your $_POST-variables. Remember that this does not check if some input fields are empty, which means that there can be a blank space in the input value without returning error.

```
// Here you set how many results there should be from $_POST (total inputs)
$totalInputs=100;

if(count($_POST) != $totalInputs)
{
    echo "You forgot to fill all fields.";
}
else
{
    // Do your MySQL query here
}
```

Hope it helps you!

---

#### Old code

Use the following PHP snippet:

```
if(!empty($postEmri) && !empty($postKlienti))
{
     $sql="UPDATE forma SET emri='$postEmri', klienti='$postKlienti', telefoni='$postTelefoni'";
}
```

PHP function empty() checks if the variable is empty or not.

More information here:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql='UPDATE forma SET ';
$appendSql = '';
if ( !empty($postEmri) ) $appendSql .= '`emri` = \" . $postEmri. \",';
if ( !empty($postKlienti) ) $appendSql .= '`klienti` = \" . $postKlienti. \",';
etc.

if ( !empty($appendSql)  ) {
    $sql =. $appendSql;
    $sql = substr($sql, 0, -1); 
    // Do query
} else {
    // Nothing to do, since nothing changed.
}
```